# Is SQL Server a write-only dbms?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, nvarchar

I'm facing a really wierd problem and cannot figure out how to solve it.

C# app, uses Entity Framework 6.1.

In my model I have a string property named `jsonData` which I use to store Json data of arbitrary length (from some KB up to 20-30 MB).

Code-first migration created an `nvarchar(max)` column. When I write to this column things go ok.

Even if using SSMS i cannot see the entire content of the filed, I know that data is stored regularly; using

```
SELECT LEN(jsonData) 
FROM Stats 
WHERE id = 1
```

I get the right length (let's say 371130)

But if I try to read the column I get only 44K back (45056 chars)

```
Stats mystat = db.Stats.Find(1);
mystat.jsonData.length = 43679
```

This is driving me crazy; data is written but I cannot read it back...

Is it an EF issue?

Is it a global param in SQL Server?

Any hint?

**EDIT**
The model is

```
public class Stat
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public string jsonData { get; set; }
    public string dataProcessed { get; set; }
}
```

This is code writing data

```
        <snip>
        string stats = "some string data bigger than 44kB";
        </snip>
        mystat.jsonData = stats;
        mystat.dataProcessed = ".Yes";
        db.SaveChanges();
```

This code reads data

```
        Stat mystat = db.Stats.Find(id);
        if (mystat != null)
        {
            string tmpstring = mystat.jsonData;
        }
```

After reading tmpstring, its lenght is 43679.
If i go to SSMS,

```
 SELECT len(jsonData) from Stat where id=1

 => 371130
```

This is MAGIC.

Comment: Which data type do you use while transferring data from SQL Server database to UI? It should not be limited, perhaps better to use String data types

Comment: I'd suggest you try to create a [MCVE]. The answer to the question posed in the title is no.

Comment: Please show more of your code so we can better identify the underlying problem.

Comment: Is the result the same if you use `Stat mystat = db.Stats.SingleOrDefault(s=>s.id==id);` instead of `.Find`?